# Nginx Map Redirect Rule

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect the following

From Original URI:

```
ui/abc/def/vsphere.core.folder.manage?objectId=urn:vmomi:Folder:group-d1:5555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111
```

Into Redirect URI:

```
/ui
```

My desire is if the URI contain `5555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111` in the URL (don't care whatever before it), then it will be redirect to `/ui`

I tried this but it doesn't work. Please help me. Many thanks

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default 0;

~^5555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111(.*)?$ /ui;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression only matches URIs which **begin with** `5555-xxx`, remove the `^`.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default 0;
    ~5555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111  /ui;
}
server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) { return 301 $redirect; }
    ...
}
```